# Adding a UINavigationBar to a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

[I have added a UINavigationBar in the Table view.](http://i50.tinypic.com/rihoiu.png) I know this is not the right way to do it, but im thinking is there an other way? When im trying to put the UINavigationBar and the Table View in a View Controller or a Table View controller the console gives this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency',
reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time!
View <UITableView: 0x1ebfb200; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque
= NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1e5a0500>; layer =
<CALayer:0x1e5a94f0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}> is associated with <UITableViewController: 0x1e59f8c0>.
Clear this association before associating this view with <SheetsSavedViewController: 0x1f879660>.'
```

Now when I scroll, the navigation bar moves with the table view. Is there any way to lock it in place at the top? Or fix the above error...

Comment: Here's a nice tutorial: http://dlinsin.blogspot.it/2010/01/adding-uinavigationbar-to-uitableview.html I suggest to do it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Why not Embed the entire table view controller in a navigation view by using the menu option in the file menu.

Answer (score 0):

- Select your tableView controller in stroyboard
- Editor - > Embed In -> Navigation Controller